# Audit Logging Discrepancy: Journald vs Rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog, systemd-journald, audit, apparmor

After installing Debian 12 and rsyslog 8.2302 (for TLS remote syslog), I noticed that apparmor logs (or any audit logs) were not being sent remotely.

After reviewing the local system, journald DOES contain all the audit and apparmor logs, but rsyslog is not getting any of them. Rsyslog can see all the other normal logs.

I have `ForwardToSyslog=yes` uncommented in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, but it does not seem to make a difference.

/etc/rsyslog.conf

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file for rsyslog
#
# For more information install rsyslog-doc and see
# /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/configuration/index.html
#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

# TLS Certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog.d/logserver.crt          # Server Certificate or CA
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog.d/selfsigned.crt       # Client Certificate
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog.d/selfsigned.key        # Client Key

# TLS Sending Configuration
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls                    # use gtls netstream driver
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1                   # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name       # server is NOT authenticated

#
# TLS Remote Logging Rule
#
*.* @@192.168.3.2:6514
```

On Debian 11, apparmor logs were being forwarded by rsyslog no problem.
I also tried changing the remote line in `rsyslog.conf` to `*.* /var/log/syslog` and after restarting, no audit or apparmor logs appeared in the file (all the other system logs did though...)

I realize the removal of rsyslog from default installation with this new release, so how can one reenable rsyslog to see and ship off audit (apparmor) logs?

Comment: Typically, the imuxsock and imklog modules are now replaced by the
imjournal module which reads all the data from the systemd journal. Check if your
distribution provides this module.

Comment: Adding `module(load="imjournal")` and restarting rsyslog seems to happen without error. But audit logs are still not appearing remotely (and not appearing locally when written to file). Does this module have to be paired with a different om module than the legacy `*.* @@192.168.3.2:6514` (I did attempt using `type="omfwd"` but that yielded the same results.

Comment: `*.*` should still capture all incoming messages, so I don't know why the audit logs dont appear anymore. You might need to run rsyslogd with `-dn` in the foreground to get very copious debug output on stdout and look for hints in the startup. You should do this when the system is very quiet, and you can provoke an audit log entry to see if it arrives.

Comment: I added `module(load="mmjsonparse")` and the audit logs are showing up remotely now.

Comment: I just took another look, it looks like it wasnt rsyslog at all. I was enabling audisp-syslog plugin for auditd, and it looks like rsyslog is picking that up directly from audit rather than journal.